# how to declare a variable using an anonymous struct

Tags: c, gcc

The following code doesn't compile, I can understand why, but I need to make it work anyway, preferably in a standards compliant way.

```
extern const struct {  int x; } a;

const struct { int x; } a = {1};
```

The compiler says, "error: conflicting types for ‘a’", even though the types are identical, even though they are probably different anonymous instances.

So, how do I explain to the compiler that the two types are the same without giving the struct a name or using a typedef? Can it be done?

Comment: It's a constant, you need to initialize it on declaration

Comment: not true, you can do "extern const struct x1 { int x; } b;const struct x1 b = {1};" and it works, the snippet in the question doesn't work because the compiler is convinced the two structs are different.

Comment: the type have the same structure abut are not the same type.

Comment: is there a way to make the compiler accept the two as the same type?

Comment: I don't think you can do that but then we should wait until a very clever programmer comes up with a way :)

Comment: I don't think it's difficult to detect this, the question is, is this behavior required by a standard? or is it just a compiler conspiracy? If it's the former I'll accept it, if the latter, I'll nag and complain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two `struct` declarations declare two distinct types.

The C standard is quite clear. §6.7.2.3/p5: "Each declaration of a structure, union, or
enumerated type which does not include a tag declares a distinct type."

So in standard C, you're out of luck.

If you are prepared to use a gcc extension, the following should work:

```
extern const struct {  int x; } a;

__typeof(a) a = {1};
```

If you specify something like `-std=gnu11`, then you can even leave out the two underscores.

Comment: thank you, do you by any chance know if the standard also prohibits defining the same struct twice, e.g. "struct a {int b;}; struct a { int b; };" ?

Comment: @Martin. I'm afraid so. "A specific type shall have its content defined at most once". Same section, paragraph 1.