# Why do anonymous structs cause conflicting types

Tags: c, anonymous-struct

```c
#define MyStruct(T) struct {T data;}

void foo(MyStruct(int) s);

void foo(MyStruct(int) s) {
    return;
}

int main(void) {
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

This results in an error:

```
main.c:7:6: error: conflicting types for 'foo'
void foo(MyStruct(int) s) {
     ^
main.c:5:6: note: previous declaration is here
void foo(MyStruct(int) s);
     ^
```

There's no error if I create a typedef, such as `typedef MyStruct(int) MyIntStruct;` and use that.

So my question is, why do I get the conflicting type error? Are all anonymous structs unique, like the compiler won't determine whether they're the exact same type?

Comment: Unique means each one is different.

Comment: Yes, all struct definitions are unique and are not related to each other, be it anonymous or not.

Comment: @ruks: two occurrences of `struct some_tag;` in a program declare the same `struct` type, which is perfectly legal. I can declare `struct T;` and later define its members `struct T { … };`. Those two declarations are certainly related.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to declare a variable using an anonymous struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884450/how-to-declare-a-variable-using-an-anonymous-struct)

Comment: Even if two struct definitions contain the same members, they are still considered different structs, just as they should be.  You *want* them to be considered different.  It catches bugs.  But it's not a problem, because it makes no sense to define a struct more than once.  Define it once, in your header file (if it's exported) or at the top of your source file, and then refer to the same struct everywhere.

Comment: You already found a solution (using a `typedef`).  The other way to do it is by using a structure tag.

Comment: Are you asking about standard C or non-standard extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, these are structure declarations without tags, not anonymous structures. An *anonymous structure* is a structure without a name, not a structure declaration without a tag. For example:

```
struct outer
{
    struct inner { int x; int y; };
    int z;
} s;
```

In this code, the `struct` member inside `s` does not have a member name, so it is anonymous. We have no name that can refer to that structure, and we refer to its members as `s.x` and `s.y`, rather than `s.something.x` and `s.something.y`.

The reason each declaration of a structure without a tag declares a distinct type is C 2018 6.7.2.3 5 says:

> … Each declaration of a structure, union, or enumerated type which does not include a tag declares a distinct type.

A reason for this is sometimes we use structures that have identical contents for different purposes. For example, we might have a structure with two `double` values that we use for complex numbers (real and imaginary parts) and a structure with two `double` values that we use for points in a plane (*x* and *y* coordinates):

```
typedef struct { double d[2]; } ComplexNumber;
typedef struct { double d[2]; } Point;
```

Having the compiler treat these as different types means it can give us warnings about mistakes like passing a `Point` as an argument where a `Complex` is expected.

As you have noted, a `typedef` creates a new name for a type. Then using the `typedef` name refers to that existing type. It does not “repeat” the declaration of the `struct` and create a new type.